# .htaccess redirect link to same url but adding query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use pretty affiliate urls based on the username of my website users.

I need to redirect a link like:

```
https://example.com/anything-here/username
```

To

```
https://example.com/anything-here/?ref=user_id
```

I've found this solution:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)username(.*)$ https://example.com/?ref=user_id [L,R=301]`

It works, but redirects to the page I set here (in this case, it's the home page). My question is:

How can I redirect it to the page requested at the beginning, but removing the username and adding `/?ref=user_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You look as if you are close, you just need to make use of the *backreferences*. Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/username$ https://example.com/$1/?ref=user_id [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` is a *backreference* to the first captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Also, you don't appear to need the `(.*)` at the end of the pattern, since `username` is at the end of the URL (at least in your example).

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect - change it to 301 (permanent) if this is required.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.